# Azure AD B2C & Google APIs

Tags: google-api, azure-ad-b2c, google-my-business-api

I need help integrating Azure AD B2C and Google APIs. Briefly, I created a tenant on Azure AD B2C, policies and a Native App. Users can register to my app and sign in without any problems. Now I need to use Google APIs to access the logged-in account's information and manage some information (Google MyBusiness data). How can I achieve that. Is that possible ?

Furthermore, even if that is not connected to Azure AD B2C, how can I request to the user to accept that my app to view MyBusiness data?

UPDATE: I understand that I need to authorize my app to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage` Google scopes. Is it possible to request that scope during Google SignIn application authorization process?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: So you downvoted me because I didn't found an answer to my question. That's ok, but what is the answer....so easy to say I didn't search enought if you don't give me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official Azure AD B2C FAQ:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs

**Can I configure scopes to gather more information about consumers from various social identity providers?**

No, but this feature is on our roadmap. The default scopes used for our supported set of social identity providers are:

- Facebook: email
- Google+: email
- Microsoft account: openid email profile
- Amazon: profile
- LinkedIn: r_emailaddress, r_basicprofile

Answer (score 2):

As part of the authentication exchange between Azure AD B2C and Google (as well as other identity providers), an access token is issued by Google for use by (and only by) Azure AD B2C, where this access token is used by Azure AD B2C to access the authorized information for the authenticated end-user.

Currently, Azure AD B2C does not pass this access token through to the relying party application (i.e. your native client application), therefore applications can't access the information for the end-user.

**UPDATE on 20 June 2019**

Using a custom policy, you can [pass the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-custom) from the external identity provider through Azure AD B2C to your relying party application.

Comment: It seems that this is no longer the case, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-custom

Comment: Correct, thank you @ChiefWiggum for pointing this out, I've edited the above answer.